# How to make the google map markers's Title and Snippet always display?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In google map develop for android,I want to make the markers's title and snippet always been show no mater how much markers on the map or if I clicked the marker or the bank.
Like this(Not enough reputation for send image....):
https://plus.google.com/110339454351188867708/posts/Np5rLWyTiyz?pid=6192041010938762194&oid=110339454351188867708

What should I do.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit 1**: i found this library:

http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/

it can show many simple marker with text, but i have not used it, you can try it yourself

About [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows):

> An info window allows you to display information to the user when they
>   tap on a marker. Only one info window is displayed at a time. If a
>   user clicks on another marker, the current info window will be hidden
>   and the new info window will be displayed.

So you can not show multi info window, but you can keep info window always shows when current marker is selected by using showInfoWindow():

```
Marker currentMarker;
```

implement on map click listener:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                currentMarker.showInfoWindow();
            }
        });
```

implement on marker click listener:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                currentMarker = marker;
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: I still need to find the way for showing info windows of many markers at the same time.